# Joint distribution of two sums of correlated variables

Tags: probability, correlation, estimation, copula, joint-distribution

Suppose that $(X_1, Y_1)$ and $(X_2, Y_2)$ are independent and have the same joint distribution $F_{X,Y}$, which is a known copula $C_{X,Y}(F(X), F(Y))$. Also, suppose that $V = X_1 + X_2$ and $W = Y_1 + Y_2$.

It would be great if someone could point me to a procedure for computing the copula $C_{V,W}(F(V), F(W))$.

If not, is there is some other way (beside direct simulation) to compute the joint distribution $F_{VW}$?

Thanks!

EDIT: Added independence assumption

Comment: You need to specify the _joint distribution_ of $(X_1,X_2,Y_1,Y_2)$ in order to compute the joint distribution of $X_1+X_2$ and $Y_1+Y_2$.  Even the _marginal distribution_ of $X_1+X_2$ cannot be obtained without some information (or assumption) about the joint distribution of $X_1$ and $X_2$.

Comment: I assume that the two vectors are independent. Thanks for catching that.

Comment: The fact that it is a copula does not matter on principle. You have the joint distribution of $(X_1,X_2,Y_1,Y_2)$, from which you can derive the joint distribution of $(V,W)$ by a linear change of variables.

Answer (score 1):

The distribution of the sum of independent random variables/vectors can often be obtained easily using moment generating functions (MGF).

In short, the MGF of the sum is the product of the MGFs of the random variables/vectors.

Details on MGF can be found here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment-generating_function